# How to efficiently provide a Web, CLI & API interface in Python?

Tags: python, flask, interface, command-line-interface, python-click

My problem is as follows. There is some function in my library:

```py
def some_func(arg1=1):
    pass
```

which I want to use in three ways:

**Using import statements in other python scripts:**

```py
import my_library
my_library.some_func()
```

**Expose using a CLI interface with click.**

```py
@click.group()
@click.option('--arg1', default=1)
def some_func(arg1):
    pass
```

**Expose using a web interface with Flask.**

```py
@app.route('/endpoint', defaults={'arg1': 1})
def some_func(arg1):
    pass
```

But how can I structure this efficiently without duplicating too much code?

Is it possible to merge all three? I tried (variations of) the following, which fails:

```py
@click.group()
@click.option('--arg1', default=1)
@app.route('/endpoint', defaults={'arg1': 1})
def some_func(arg1=1):
    pass
```

Or do I really need the 3 different functions as defined above?

And if so, how should I go about the default values?

Is accessing a global variable at all places the best way to do this?

Comment: You should use three entry points, and there is nothing wrong with shared constants being used as defaults.

Comment: Thanks. But to my eye it seems so ugly to use constants for default values, but perhaps that is because I personally have not seen that "in-the-wild" yet. Therefore I try to find out if there is some better approach to creating these kind of apps.. But I have a hard time finding anything about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since decorator syntax is just a shortcut for function application, you start with defining your function in your library. Then your `click` example becomes:

```
import my_library

click.group()(click.option('--arg1', default=1)(my_library.some_func))
```

and your Flask example becomes

```
import library

app.route('/endpoint', defaults={'arg1': 1})(my_library.some_func)
```

(I know for Flask, the return value of the decorator isn't important; I assume the same is true for `click`.)

This assumes you aren't trying to use the same script as both a command-line tool and a Flask app; that doesn't make much sense IMO.

---

As far as simplifying the default value, nothing good comes to mind. Click, Flask, and your function have three different ways of indicting  default value; the only thing in common is the actual *value* of that default. You might do something like this. First, in `my_library.py`:

```
some_func_default = 1

def some_func(arg=None):  # Or some other sentinel
    if arg is None:
        arg = some_func_default
```

Then in your two other scripts:

```
click.group()(click.option('--arg1', default=my_library.some_func_default)(my_library.some_func))
```

and

```
app.route('/endpoint', defaults={'arg1': my_library.some_func_default})(my_library.some_func)
```

Granted, you could use the `inspect` module to extract the default value from your original definition of `some_func`, but that doesn't help with the difference in how Click and Flask set default values for their entry points.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your assumption is correct in that these are in fact separate  scripts. But what would then be a good option for the default values? Using global variables from `my_library`?

Comment: @MuadDev That seems as good as any. The problem is with how Click and Flask specify defaults, not with how to discover the default value.

Comment: Thanks for your additional advice. But could you explain why you'd use a sentinel value in the "my_library" definition and not just directly using the global variable like: `some_func(arg=some_func_default)`?

Comment: I'm generalizing early, in case the default value is something mutable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [hug](https://www.hug.rest/) library, which was made precisely for this use case.

Example:

```
"""An example of writing an API to scrape hacker news once, and then enabling usage everywhere"""
import hug
import requests


@hug.local()
@hug.cli()
@hug.get()
def top_post(section: hug.types.one_of(('news', 'newest', 'show'))='news'):
    """Returns the top post from the provided section"""
    content = requests.get('https://news.ycombinator.com/{0}'.format(section)).content
    text = content.decode('utf-8')
    return text.split('<tr class=\'athing\'>')[1].split("<a href")[1].split(">")[1].split("<")[0]
```

Comment: Seems interesting, thanks for pointing me towards this resource!